# Why input validators IPAddress, Length do not provide user any error message, but just prevent him from submitting button?

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

Need advice regarding WTForms Flask: I need to use ip address validator and maximum length validator (IPAddress, Length) - they works, but do not give user any error messages, on the other hand InputRequired validator works fine. I checked documentation and have no idea what could be the problem with the code.

// app.py file:

```py
    from flask import Flask, render_template
    from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
    from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField
    from wtforms.validators import InputRequired, IPAddress, Length


    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.secret_key = "test"

    StringField()

    class MyForm(FlaskForm):
       inp_required_str = StringField("Input required: ", validators= 
       [InputRequired()])
       max_len_str = StringField("Max length < 5: ", validators= 
       [InputRequired(), Length(max=5, message="Less than 5!")])
       ip_address_str = StringField("Is ip address: ", validators= 
       [InputRequired(), IPAddress(message="Should be ip!")])
       button = SubmitField("Click me!")


     @app.route('/', methods=["GET", "POST"])
     def hello_world():
        form = MyForm()
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            # do some work here
            return render_template("test.html", form=form, message="Fine?")
        return render_template("test.html", form=form)


   if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run()
```

// html template:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post">
            {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
            {{form.inp_required_str.label}}  {{form.inp_required_str}} <br> 
            <br>
            {{form.max_len_str.label}}  {{form.max_len_str}} <br> <br>
            {{form.ip_address_str.label}}  {{form.ip_address_str}} <br> <br>
            {{form.button}} <br> <br>
        </form>
        <h1>{{ message }}</h1>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not rendering the error messages that get returned by calling `validate_on_submit`. You need to add some kind of logic to do that for you. InputRequired validator works fine because Wtforms adds an required attribute to your input field and that is managed by the browser itself.

I would suggest you use a macro for that as stated [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/patterns/wtforms/):

```
{% macro render_field(field) %}
  <dt>{{ field.label }}
  <dd>{{ field(**kwargs)|safe }}
  {% if field.errors %}
    <ul class=errors>
    {% for error in field.errors %}
      <li>{{ error }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% endif %}
  </dd>
{% endmacro %}
```

Comment: It works now! Thanks! Is there any chance receive error messages for IPAddress, Length without submitting input with WTForms?

Comment: Not natively with WTForms. Validation is __only__ performed on the server side, so there is no way to check for errors without submitting the form. If you wanted to do checks on the client side, you most likely are going to need some kind of Javascript logic. BUT you still need validation on the server side to prevent security issues. Client-side validation only provides a nicer user experience.